# Latex Error "log file not found"

Tags: texmaker

I'm using Texmaker and I get this error "Log file not found" when I am running LatexPDF.
Can you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Rachelle What exactly is the workflow here? I assume you are creating a `.tex` file, then trying to run something, then getting the warning?

Comment: Yes, exactly when i run any .tex file, then this warning pops up..

Comment: If you have checked the option "use build directory..." then you can disable it or add the flag `--output-directory=./build` to your PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLatex script, for example, mine is: `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape --output-directory=./build %.tex`

Answer (score 12):

This error can occur if you have no TEX engine installed.
Because TexMaker is only a editor and can therefor not compile tex code without a Tex distro installed previously.

If you are working on windows, make sure to install either TexLive or MikTex.
http://www.tug.org/texlive/

For Mac there is MacTex.
http://tug.org/mactex/

Hope this helps

Comment: In this case please remember to mark this question as solved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If somebody still encouters the problem, try to uncheck the "use a build subdirectory for output files" box. For me this in combination with Peiqins tip worked.

Comment: can't we make that a global option in the Tex Distribution (MacTex in my case)?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem in Linux OS, and I run the command line to compile the .tex file first to generate a .log file in the directory. Then it can be compiled by Texmaker without errors.

Also this error occurs when you give a name with symbols like ! %&$# etc... make sure you didn't gave a name with symbols an try.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after trying many ways to solve the problem, I noticed that the name of the file I had to compile contained two spaces; I just renamed it and everything work fine.