# Error when compiling xcolor.ins in TeXmaker to generate xcolor.sty file

Tags: errors, installing, texmaker

I have downloaded `xcolor.ins` and `xcolor.dtx` from

http://kern.heimat.eu/tex/xcolor.html

These two files are in the same folder.

When I run the `.ins` file I get the error message `Log file not found`. The `.ins` file is a simple script added below.

```
\def\batchfile{xcolor.ins}

\input docstrip.tex

\askforoverwritefalse

\generate{\file{xcolor.lox}{\from{xcolor.dtx}{extract}}}

\batchinput{xcolor.lox}

\endbatchfile
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: You have to download the file xcolor200.zip, extract it and then follow the instructions in the README

Comment: Yes the README only tells to extract the files from the .dtx file and that should be what the .ins file does I believe when looking at the code. Maybe I have missed something

Comment: Are you using TeXmaker? I think this might be common problem with that editor. Perhaps run it from the command line: `latex xcolor.ins`.

Comment: ok this may seem really basic. But how should I do to run it from the command line. I use TeXmaker so it is most likely that problem I have. However I am not sure how to use the command line in TeXmaker. I have tried to run it from the command Prompt but it only says file is not found.

Comment: ok it seemed to work when I ran it in the command prompt thanks for all

Answer (score 3):

**Method :1 Using `User Command` in TeXmaker** to run `.ins` file in TeXmaker

- TeXmaker is default configured for normal users to run `.tex` files

  `latex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
- Inorder to make TeXmaker run `.ins` extension files add an User Command Name `latex-ins-run`

  `latex %.ins`  as shown in screenshots below

**Step 1: Locating the `User Command`**

[image]

**Step 2: Defining User Command Name as `latex-ins-run`**

[image]

**Step 3: Executing `latex-ins-run` from a list of options**

[image]

> Finally once you press `latex-ins-run command` `xcolor.ins` is compiled with `latex`

[image]

**Method :2 Running Terminal/Commandline in TeXmaker** to get the `.sty`

- TeXmaker--> File menu-->Tools--> Open Terminal
- At Terminal/Commandline `latex xcolor.ins`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

TeXmaker [has](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117679/5764) [some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66763/5764) [known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63999/5764) [issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117631/5764) in this regard. However, in this instance, you don't need to run the file `xcolor.ins` from within TeXmaker; a command-line approach is sufficient.

```
latex xcolor.ins
```

Comment: Usually a default configuration(targetting beginners who use mostly `.tex` file) in TeXmaker has `latex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` expecting a `.tex` file as input to `latex` engine hence `.ins` is not recognised. Your guess with IDE was right. It is _not a bug/issue_ (may be potential feature request) with TeXmaker in my view but can be customized Using `User Command` option.